# Демультиплексирование потоковых данных (webm)

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc, mediarecorder, .webm

Существуют ли готовые решения для демультиплексирования потоковых данных (webm)? Смотрел в сторону библиотеки [libwebm](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm), но, похоже, что она больше подходит для работы с файлами, нежели с потоковыми данными.

Данный вопрос возник в контексте разработки десктопного приложения на базе Electron, которое используется для получения видео с мобильных устройств по протоколу WebRTC с последующим декодированием и передачей полученных данных кастомного драйверу (с помощью аддона, написанного на C++).

Более детально:

1. При [добавлении](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/ontrack) нового трека мы извлекаем из него [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) и передаем его в конструктор [MediaRecorder'а](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).
2. Запускаем MediaRecorder, указывая ненулевое значение для параметра [timeslice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start).
3. Когда очередная [порция данных готова](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable), мы передаем их в аддон, который с помощью libwebm должен демультиплексировать потоковые данные на аудио и видео, декодировать их, и отправить в соответствующий драйвер.

Сейчас для демультиплексирования используется libwebm (с небольшими изменениями), происходит это следующим образом:

- читаем EBML заголовок контейнера (webm)
- создаем сегмент, инициализируем, делаем [load](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm/blob/master/mkvparser/mkvparser.cc#L1448) (но **без загрузки** кластеров, см. определение `Segment::Load`)
- загружаем очередной кластер, в случае успеха перебираем блоки, извлекаем видео фреймы и аудио данные, передаем их соответствующим декодерам, в противном случае - ждем новой порции данных

Все ломается после того, как возникает необходимость перезаписать буфер - когда очередная порция данных не может быть записана [в буфер], "остаток" необработанных данных копируется в начало буфера, затем запиcь продолжается в обычном режиме. Если я правильно понимаю суть проблемы, то все дело в том, что сегмент хранит различные позиции и отступы (что приемлемо, когда речь идет о файлах), которые становятся невалидными после того, как происходит очередная перезапись буфера.

Возможно, кто-то уже занимался чем-то подобным и сможет предложить решение или другой вариант того, как это можно реализовать.

*P.S. Если у кого-то есть опыт разработки WebRTC-приложений с помощью нативного API - буду весьма признателен, если поделитесь ссылками\проектами. Лично меня данный вариант отпугнул объемами кода chromium/webrtc и способом, которым это все собирается :)*